# How should I arrange my if...else if in C?

Tags: c, if-statement

My school teacher teaches `if...else if` today. She teaches us to write the `if...else if` like this

```
if(x == 1) {
    //some code here
}
else if(x == 2) {
    //some code here
}
    else if(x == 3) {
        //some code here
    }
        else if (x == 4) {
            //some code here
        }
```

But, from what I learn from Internet is mostly write like this

```
if(x == 1) {
    //some code here
}
else if(x == 2) {
    //some code here
}
else if(x == 3) {
    //some code here
}
else if (x == 4) {
    //some code here
}
```

So, my question is which should I follow? Internet or my teacher ? I never seen anybody write `if...else if` like my teacher before.

p.s. I know these two will give same result when running it. Just confusing how should I arrange the `if...else if` statement.

Comment: You should follow whatever coding standard is imposed upon you.  If your teacher demands that, you should use it.  But you are right in that it is extremely nonstandard.

Comment: The answer to this question will be opinion-based, but I can state as fact that your teacher's style is rather unusual.

Comment: The top example would make sense if the statements were nested (e.g. `if { if { ... } } else { ... }`), but in my opinion indentation without a change in block-scope is improper formatting and misleading. I call the latter form "flat code", and personally find it _much_ easier to read (and good to strive for, to un-nest several levels of code blocks)

Comment: The second is more conventional, your teacher's approach is very unorthodox though. A rule of thumb is that different projects will have different styling guidelines/requirements, so you adapt according to that. But as a general guideline, the second example is much better for readability.

Comment: True enlightenment tends to proceed in stages.  In the case of code indentation, at first you indent things randomly.  Then you discover that's impossible to follow, so you start imposing rules, like that each `else` should line up with the corresponding `if`.  Then you notice that a strict application of this rule causes a long `if`/`else`/`if`/`else` chain to march off the right edge of the screen, and you realize that since `if`/`else`/`if`/`else` is a useful specialized idiom, it's worthwhile adding an exception to the strict  rule. Sounds like your teacher's still at stage 2.

Comment: You should use a `switch` statement here.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I never indented randomly. I went straight from no indent to block indent.

Answer (score 1):

I normally don't like style debates, but your teacher chose a really strange style indeed.

You are correct, almost everybody writes else if like in your second example, even when the local standard calls for never using single statement blocks with curly braces omitted, as though `else if` were a keyword with a space in it.

I have seen people ban it, but everybody else who does so always ends up with

```
    else {
        if () {
        }
    }
```

or a variant of it where one or more opening braces go on their own lines.

We should remember that `else if` ladders get very long indeed and a style that requires indenting them becomes intolerable after while. Most languages that have more rigid whitespace rules (I'm looking at you Visual Basic) end up with an `elseif` keyword to avoid this problem.